# Using MSAL.js to integrate React Single-page applications with Azure Active Directory

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I'm learning about authentication on React application using MSAL and I was following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oPSL5wWeS0

I created an application in Microsoft tenant

and made the code updates:

index.tsx

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';


export const pca = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: 'clientId',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId',
    redirectUri: '/'
  }
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
    <App/>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import { SignInButton } from './components/SignInButton';
import { MsalProvider} from "@azure/msal-react";
import { pca } from "./index";


function App() {
  
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
      <SignInButton />      
    </MsalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SignInButton.tsx

```
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

export const SignInButton = () => {
    const { instance } = useMsal();

    const handleSignIn = () => {
        instance.loginRedirect({
            scopes: ['user.read']
        });
    }

    return (
        <DefaultButton onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign in</DefaultButton>
    )
};
```

and on running the app, I see this error immediately after I click on 'SignIn' button:

[image]

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got results as below:***

I registered one Azure AD application(SPA) and added **redirect URI** as http://localhost:3000 like this:

[image]

Now I cloned **same** `msal-react` sample and modified code as below:

**App.js**

```js
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { PageLayout } from "./components/PageLayout";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Profile } from "./pages/Profile";

import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";


function App({msalInstance}) {
    return (
        <MsalProvider instance = {msalInstance}>
        <PageLayout>
            <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                <Pages />
            </Grid>
        </PageLayout>
        </MsalProvider>
    );
}

const Pages = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**SignInButton.jsx**

```js
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';


export const SignInButton = () => {
    const {instance} = useMsal();

    const handleSignIn = () => {
        instance.loginRedirect({
            scopes: ['user.read']
        });
    }

    return (
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign in</Button>
    )
};
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { theme } from "./styles/theme";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from './App';

import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const pca = new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: '7006179e-2a1a-4790-9847-xxxxxxxxx',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxx',
        redirectUri: '/',
    }
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <App msalInstance={pca} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image]

When I ran http://localhost:3000 in browser, I got below screen:

[image]

After clicking `Sign In` button, I got login screen to pick account like below:

[image]

When I selected account in which application with provided **client ID** exists, I got consent screen like this:

[image]

After approving the consent, user signed in successfully with below screen:

[image]

In your case, check whether you are passing **AppID** of application in `clientId` parameter or not.

To reproduce the error, I changed code by replacing AppID with **ObjectID** of application in `clientId` parameter

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { theme } from "./styles/theme";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from './App';

import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const pca = new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: 'bfd0d11b-0dd4-4acd-bbab-xxxxxxxxxx',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxx',
        redirectUri: '/',
    }
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <App msalInstance={pca} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image]

I got **same error** immediately after I clicking `Sign In` button like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass `AppID` of application that can be found here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My client if is correct. Did you run it locally? Do I have to be an admin of the tenant where I create the application to get it working?

Comment: Actually I created and ran it with admin credentials, didn't try with normal user.

Comment: So could you please try creating an app in the tenant where you are you are not an admin and see if that reproduces the error?

Comment: Sure will try that and get back to you in some time

Comment: Thank you! Can you please also add your code from App.tsx and SignInButton.tsx?

Comment: Added, you can check the updated answer!

Comment: where do you call SignInButton.jsx?

Comment: I now see no error. But when I click login button, it just reloads the page instead of showing login screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252537/discussion-between-sridevi-and-user989988).